# Trying to show to get two relative layouts to scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, layout, scrollview

Here is the design for my screen:
[image]

The Green border indicates the visible screen.
At first the user would only be able to see relative View 1 and the Scrollview would not do anything.
After the user presses the button to show the 2nd relative view, the 2nd relative goes from invisible to visible and the view is now scrollable (because the screen is extended)

I have nested my layouts as followed

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
      <RelativeLayout1>
      <RelativeLayout2>
</ Closing for each layout>
```

My problem is that my either my Relative View 1 will not stretch to fit the screen or if it does stretch to fit the screen, I will not be able to scroll down to relative view two.

I've tried to play around with match_parent,fill_parent,wrap_content on all different levels but haven't found a solution to my problem. Any suggestions on how I would create fix this?

Comment: Please send your whole layout.. you have to user relative layout instead linear layout

Comment: @janki there's a lot of stuff within each layer that I don't want to copy and paste due to wall of text. Why must I use relative layout instead of LinearLayout. I've tried to use Relative Layout and it causes my other layouts to shrink in size

Answer (score 0):

Your design looks like you wanted to implement something expandable view. Try this [Link](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2456)

Comment: Played around with it a bit and found out that scrolling doesn't really work with the expandable view